# how to get origin returned object

Tags: c#, nancy

```
Get["/"] = _ =>"some data";
Post["/"] = _ =>new {detail="detail.."};
```

I need convert response to this format

```
{
   state: state code
   data: origin data
}
```

So, I add a after hook

```
After.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(ResponseFormatHook);
...
private void ResponseFormatHook(NancyContext ctx)
{
    var apiResponse = new APIResponse();
    apiResponse.State = ctx.Response.StatusCode;

    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ctx.Response.Contents.Invoke(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            // get the origin data
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            apiResponse.Data = content;
        }
    }

    var response = new JsonResponse(apiResponse, new DefaultJsonSerializer());
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    ctx.Response = response;
}
```

For `Get["/"]`,it's ok. will return `{state:200,data:"some data"}`.

But for `Post["/"]`,will return `{state:200,data:"{detail:\"detail..\"}"}`.The data convert to a string not object.The client can not deserialize at once.

So, how can I get the origin data?

`apiResponse.Data=OriginData`, this will be OK.

**EDIT 1**

Maybe I can deserialize the Data like

`apiResponse.Data=JsonConvert.Deserialize(apiResponse.Data)`.

But I think this cost too much,isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IResponseProcessor` will touch the origin data.

```
public class APIResponseProcessor : IResponseProcessor
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<Tuple<string, MediaRange>> extensionMappings =
        new[] {new Tuple<string, MediaRange>("json", MediaRange.FromString("application/json"))};

    public ProcessorMatch CanProcess(MediaRange requestedMediaRange, dynamic model, NancyContext context)
    {
        var match = new ProcessorMatch();
        match.ModelResult = MatchResult.DontCare;
        match.RequestedContentTypeResult = MatchResult.ExactMatch;

        return match;
    }

    public Response Process(MediaRange requestedMediaRange, dynamic model, NancyContext context)
    {
        var apiResponse = new APIResponse();
        apiResponse.Data = model;

        return new JsonResponse(apiResponse,new DefaultJsonSerializer());
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, MediaRange>> ExtensionMappings { get { return extensionMappings; } }
}
```

Use processor instead of After hook.